# prevent a particular field from editing in sitecore in experience editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have a rich text field. I wanted to know if there is way to prevent this rich text field from editable using experience editor in  Sitecore.

Say suppose I have multiple rich text fields,

1. Banner content
2. Abstract content
3. Body content

Out of these how to I prevent only Banner content from editing, remaining 2 fields can be edited from page editor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are multiple options.

You haven't shared your code, so I'll paste only few of them:

1. When using a Sitecore control:

```xml
 <sc:Text Field="Banner content" DisableWebEditing="true" runat="server" />
```

2. When using the Sitecore MVC helper:

```cs
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Banner content", new { disable-web-editing=true })
```

Update for Sitecore 8: `{ DisableWebEdit = true }`

3. When using the FieldRenderer.Render() method directly:

```cs
FieldRenderer.Render("Banner content", "disable-web-editing=true")
```

More in Chapter 2 of  [Sitecore CMS 7 and later
Page Editor Recommended
Practices for Developers](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/page_editor_recommended_practices_for_developers_70-a4.pdf)